# How to Display Last Record of a Specific ID number?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table having below fields.

```
DrawingId    DrawingNumber   Revision
111              555555                  0
111              555555                  1
111              555555                  2
111              555555                  3
111              555555                  4
```

I want to display the Last Record through Query.

Kindly guide me how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a single ID, you could use the following:

```sql
select top 1 t.* from YourTable t where t.drawingid = 111 order by t.revision desc
```

Change `YourTable` to suit your table name.

Comment: how to use code if Drawing Number is being select from Combo Box ?

Comment: Assuming that `drawingid` is the bound column of the combobox, change `111` to reference your combobox, e.g. `[Forms]![YourFormName]![YourComboBoxName]`